# Mantafow not rendering smoke

Tags: cycles-render-engine, animation, smoke-simulation, versions

I have a mantaflow smoke+fire simulation, It renders perfectly fine in the viewport however when I go to hit render, the smoke does not appear here is an example:(pictured)[image]

I have checked:

Outliner all objects set to render in render view

volume samples 0

correct material nodes

a cube with principled volume renders just fine

Version number 2.83, mac os Catalina 10.15.4

- AMD Radeon Pro 5500M 4 GB

Intel UHD Graphics 630 1536 MB

2.3 GHz 8-Core Intel Core i9

16 GB 2667 MHz DDR4

Here is the project file:https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ok_25i_7pQ1pfB07MOFqQYy3exowks45/view?usp=sharing

there are no textures but the problem with the smoke is still there

Thank you for your help

Comment: Did you bake the simulation?

Comment: yes, I did openVBD

Comment: Yeah, not sure then. I've seen a lot of people complaining about issues related to smoke and fire (since 2.83). Solutions have ranged from baking the simulation to updating graphics drivers, but the results are inconsistent. I'm starting to get the feeling something might be a bit broken.

Comment: Yea haha I just tested it with 2.82 and all works fine, definitely a bug